# Searching for app takes me to 4oh4 page

Tags: facebook, search, http-status-code-404

I have a simular problem as in this [post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7352494/app-page-used-to-resolve-from-facebook-search-now-it-4oh4s). When I search for iStatus+ and clicking on the app in the search results, I am redirected to http://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php.

Sandbox mode is disabled. Here's a [screenshot](http://cl.ly/1R0x2Z0O2L2I2Y2v1J2R).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a programming question and answer site. It has a partnership with Facebook, but this is to help people with programming on Facebook's platform, not to provide support for Facebook in general. Please visit the official [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help) instead. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks! Alright, my bad. I thought this question was okay since a similar post appeared in the post that I linked to. But it's been noted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plug a URL into the Bookmark URL field:
[image]

This is a [bug logged with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/204664672932552) and that is the known workaround.